# how to reload parent page on closing Iframe- Fancybox version 5

Tags: fancybox

I want to refresh my parent page using `afterClose` on `fancybox version 5`

```
afterClose: function () { parent.location.reload(true); });
```

This was working okay on `version 3` fancybox but not working on `v5`

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow the documentation - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/api/events/ - and choose an appropriate event, in your case it would most likely be a "close" event.

Answer (score 0):

on v5 you can use the following

```
Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox="gallery"]', {
  on: {
    "destroy": (fancybox, eventName) => {
        window.location.reload();
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and asked many questions on this site, but without answers.

I finally found the solution with the option: `Hash:false`

Reference: https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/plugins/hash/